# Ruby on Rails Controllers and Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does every controller made require some type of model that goes along with it. I am still a little unclear as to the relation between the model and the controller in the MVC concept.

Comment: No, not every controller requires some type of model that goes along with it. In fact, controllers and models are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you don't need any logic based on a model,model's duty is to deal with logic.